# does Calafia airlines allow a personal item?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

They allow; Carry on luggage
10 kg Size: 108 linear cm (45 cm x 38 cm x 25 cm)
but nothing said about a personal item.
Most do but....

Comment: Cessna or Embraer. The rules on the Cessnas are brutal, they weigh and charge by the 100g.

Comment: what is personal item ?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Many airlines allow you to bring two pieces of luggage into the cabin: a standard-sized carry-on bag, plus one smaller item such as a woman's handbag or a laptop bag. The smaller item is referred to as a "personal item"

Answer (score 1):

From [Airlines-airports.com](https://airlines-airports.com/calafia-airlines-hand-cabin-baggage/):

> One piece of hand baggage is allowed  for  travelling on routes
>   covered by cessna 208 Carvan aircraft may carry up to 5 kg and
>   travelling for Embraer 120 or Embraer 145 aircraft may carry  up to 10
>   kilograms. It should be stowed under the seat in front of you or in
>   the overhead bins.

so as per the comment, they're much stricter on the Cessnas.  You may however have them giving you some leniency, but if it's full or a problem, they're going to point to their rules :/

**edit**: found their [official site with their rules](https://www.calafiaairlines.com/Servicios/Equipaje#/equipaje_mano)

> Calafia Airlines allows each passenger, including minors, to carry 1
>   piece of Hand on board at no additional charge. Hand baggage shall
>   weigh according to the following Specifications:
>
> Passengers traveling on routes covered by the aircraft Cessna 208 Caravan May carry with them a piece of baggage of hand in cabin of up
>   to 5 kilograms and maximum 108 linear centimeters (45cm x 38cm x
>   25cm).
>   Passengers traveling on routes covered by the aircraft Embraer 120 or Embraer 145 may carry with them up to a piece of cabin baggage of
>   up to 10 kilograms. This baggage must not exceed 10kg and maximum 108
>   linear centimeters (45cm x 38cm x 25cm).
>       Due to health reasons, passengers who need to be injected during the flight, are allowed to bring syringes with them. They must request
>   for a medical proof to validate their situation (a letter from the
>   doctor will be enough), and show it on the documentation process or
>   the security checking. Passengers must have this document ready to
>   show as many times as it is required.